# how to include stateful operation in your tensorflow graph?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation, lstm

I wanted to insert a LSTM into Fully Convolutional Neural Network(FCN) using tensorflow. That is, after the fifth convolutional layer, we got an tensor of the shape (14, 14, 512), and I resize this tensor to its original spatial size(229, 229, 512).  What I wanted to do next is to segment this tensor into superpixels(say, 1000 superpixels), and then feed them into a LSTM one by one.

Here is the question:

I wanted the whole structure end-to-end trainable. But we lost the spatial information after letting the superpixels go into the LSTM. I have to map the features (after LSTM) back to their original spatial positions so that it can continue to flow in the FCN. This kind of mapping is stateful operation in tensorflow, which does not let gradient flow back to the very beginning of the graph during back-propagation.

Can I still train the whole structure end-to-end? I knew people have done that in Caffe, but I'm not sure if it is doable in tensorflow? I hope it's my mistake instead of tensorflow's limitation. Thank you

*Notes*: Actually I am implementing a new LSTM structure, and I am not sure if the existing APIs can help. I would try to be more specific to the problem.

**Say I segment the tensor (229, 229, 512) into 4 regions A,B,C,D. Among them, A and B are neighbors to each other. There are 4 LSTM corresponds to each Region, LSTMa, LSTMb, LSTMc and LSTMd. When I feed in the feature of B to LSTMb, it will be affected by the hidden state of LSTMa.(Because they are neighbors). So I need to save the hidden state of LSTMa somewhere in the tensorflow graph, and call it when A's neighbors are being updated. But it seems that those operations, such as replacing a row in a matrix(tf.scatter_update), are stateful operations, which have no gradient. So the whole architecture might not be end-to-end trainable because of this?**

Comment: The easiest way to add an LSTM into your network is to use the TensorFlow APIs for RNNs, such as [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn), which are composible with other layers and end-to-end trainable. Have you tried doing this, and can you share some code and error message to indicate what went wrong?

Comment: The code contains several files and lots of lines, it might be too long to post.  I will first try to describe the problem neatly.

Comment: @mrry I've updated my question, I hope this make it clear. I could share the code with you if this doesn't help. Thanks